# Why does ffmpeg.exe -version not give simple version of software? Windows 10 - 64bit

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, version

24/Sept/2019 Ok, simple right. Not for the new users out there. You type ffmpeg -version does not give you the simple version of the current ffmpeg.exe that you just downloaded off the web site. Instead you get a "plethora" of information about a mass of version info from the -version tag you just used. Witch is needed for obvious reasons. But you don't get the version of ffmpeg you just downloaded. Download version 4.2.1 64bit windows and run the ffmpeg -version in the cmd.exe terminal and get the info that say's you have version 4.2.1 64bit. Why does it not show?

[image: no simple version listed in ffmpeg.exe]

Answer (score 2):

## You don't have version 4.2.1

You downloaded the "nightly git build" which is newer than 4.2.1. This is the default selection on Zeranoe. This is recommended for general usage. Additionally, if you asked for help on any official FFmpeg help/bug resources you would be asked to use the nightly git build before trying anything else. If you want 4.2.1 then you first need to click the 4.2.1 button before clicking "Download Build".

[image]

## Output description

```
ffmpeg -version

ffmpeg version N-95053-g95e5396919 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
     commit no. ---^        ^------ the short git hash for the commit your version
                                    derived from. Ignore the `g` prefix: it just 
                                    means "git".
built with gcc 9.1.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvpx --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus
                ^----- The options used to configure ffmpeg
libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100
libavcodec     58. 58.101 / 58. 58.101
libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100
libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102
libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
                ^----- major.minor.micro versions of each library
```

4.2.1 looks like:

```
ffmpeg version n4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
```

Comment: Um, just to clarify on the download page I pick version 4.2.1 64bit static as that's the default download right? the other builds are different as they share or need to be built. you mentioned "nightly build" there is not a link that mentions that. There is a mention in the paragraph at the top of the page " Nightly git builds are licensed as GPL 3.0" but no other mentions of nightly builds.

Comment: @snowcatman The "nightly git build" (as Zeranoe calls it in the mouseover message when you mouse over the 20190923-3104100 button) is selected by default for me. It's the one currently labeled "20190923-3104100". If I were to click "Download Build" that's what I would get. If I want 4.2.1 then I would have to click 4.2.1 first before clicking "Download Build".

Comment: Thank you. Thank you, Thank you. I Went over that again, and again. I had to refresh this post page in order to see llogan's image and post.